# Need help dissecting this Numpy slicing code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sorry, cant post any links because no reputation points.

Below is the code I am getting tripped up on:

Forecast out is an integer equal to about 30.

```
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))
```

below he is creating an array from a pandas dataframe. The array contains the same values as the df but without the df column 'label'.

```
X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
```

scaling for accuracy and processing speed

```
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
```

these are the statements I'm confused about. I see he is creating two numpy arrays from the above array X. My best guess: If we take forecast_out to be equal to 30, the first line below says to create a new array X_Lately that is equal to the last #30 rows of array X. Is this correct?

```
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
```

I have no idea what this part means. Is it a valid syntax to have an integer enclosed by ':' ?

```
X = X[:forecast_out:]
```

Anything will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please post ```df.head()```.  What is preprocessing?

Comment: Yes, ```X[-forecast_out:]``` is the last `forecast_out` rows.  For the second, are you sure there isn't a typo? That doesn't look correct - did you try it? What did it do?

Comment: The slice `:forecast_out:` is the same as `:forecast_out`.  It gives the first `forecast_out` elements.  The optional third part of a slice is the step size.  The most general form of the slice notation is `start:stop:step`.  `:forecast_out:` specifies just the `stop` value, so the start and step are the default values, which are 0 and 1, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I made a mistake in my origional post. I was looking for ':-forecast_out:' I see that it gives all the rows besides the last forecast_out rows and, '-forecast_out:' prints the last forecast_out rows. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments `:x` is exactly the samee as `:x:`:

```
>>> class peek:
...    def __getitem__(self, key):
...       return key
... 
>>> a = peek()
>>> a[:4]
slice(None, 4, None)
>>> a[:4:]
slice(None, 4, None)
```

Which is why the form that confused you isn't used very often.